# Calculating AC power figure using the DC current consumption

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, mains

In a system where I have 220V AC recitified/regulated/converted into 3.3V DC through a transformer and a voltage regulator, would the amount of current I will be drawing from the AC line equal to the amount of DC current that I consume plus the inefficiency of the AC-DC conversion?

As an example: if my DC current consumption is 200mA at 3.3V and I know that my hypothetical AC-DC conversion is 80% efficient, would I then say my circuit consumes 52.8 watts? (200mA plus a 20% extra = 240mA, 0.24 * 220 = 52.8W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the input current is **not** similar to the output current for any reasonable power supply circuit (things like dropping resistors don't count- you'd be throwing away 45W to get 0.7W). Things like transformers and switching power supplies (lossless to a first order) have output **power** that is similar to input **power**.

A well designed switching power supply adapter (wall wart kind of thing) could probably put out 3.3V at 0.2A with 70-80% efficiency, so the input power would be less than 1W. The current will, in general, be a bit higher than that would suggest because it won't behave quite like a resistive load, but that's the power you would pay for in a residence.

If you use a 50Hz transformer and knock the voltage down to (say) 6V then use a linear regulator to get 3.3V, you will lose half the power in the regulator and the efficiency might be such that you'd require 2W of power (the 50Hz transformer will have some core and copper losses too). If you knock the voltage down to (say) 12V and use a switching regulator, the losses might be similar to the switching power supply adapter as above (1W of power from the mains).

You can't just multiply input current times voltage to get power either. Not unless the load is just a simple resistor. A capacitor or a transformer with no load will draw current without consuming much power.

Comment: Good on the "linear regulator" Spehro.  I completely missed on that.

Comment: @Marla There's a few misconceptions to cover off.

Answer (score 2):

Your useage of 3.3 * 0.2  =  0.66 watts

You should have multiplied like this : 3.3v * .24 = 0.792 watts

For a rough estimate, you can use this method to estimate consumption at 220 VAC as :  0.792/220 =  3.6 mA.

However, this does not take into account the current drawn by the primary of the transformer alone.  You would have to measure the current draw of the transformer when there was no load, and add this to the additional 3.6 mA.

The current due to the primary winding is mostly reactive, and not consumed as power, but still counts in the total primary current.

Comment: See Spehro answer below, as I neglected to take into account possibility of linear regulator.